# How do I prevent HP BIOS from remapping my function keys? Or map them back without reboot?

Tags: windows, keyboard, bios, reboot, function-keys

I want to prevent my machine firmware from mapping the function keys on the keyboard in the way that HP thinks that they should be mapped, and map them in the way that I think that they should be mapped.

I have an HP ENVY laptop (but I suspect that this could apply to any Windows PC, at least with this HP firmware) running Windows 8.1.

In my opinion, HP has it backwards with Function keys.

HP is now, on models such as the Envy<sup>1</sup>, setting up the function key row on such systems as what it calls *action keys*. This is how they are configured in the *factory default*, now.<sup>2</sup>.  It gives the keyboard uses like these:
* <kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd> dim display/brighten display
* <kbd>F5</kbd> keyboard backlight toggle
* <kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> sound volume control
* et cetera

I prefer the "traditional" mapping:
* <kbd>F2</kbd> rename file in folder; edit Excel cell; ...
* <kbd>F3</kbd> repeat search
* <kbd>F5</kbd> refresh
* et cetera

Whenever HP updates the BIOS, it resets the function keys to its factory default "action key" mappings.  And then next time that I reboot these changes appear.

Now I *could* reboot my machine *again*, enter the firmware SETUP utility, and manually re-program the keys to my chosen settings, and then reboot a third time.  The weblog post cited below<sup>3</sup> explains how to re-set things this way.

But is there a way to display and change these keyboard mappings from within Windows at runtime, so that I *do not have to reboot* in order to set the keyboard back to the way that I like it?

### References

1. [*Disable The Fn + Function Key Combination on Certain Models*](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108).  Support.  HP.
2. "Using the action keys".  [*HP Envy 15 User Guide*](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01933145.pdf).  HP.  p.26.
3. GizmoGladstone (2012-05-01). [*HOW-TO: Disable The Fn + Function on HP Laptops*](http://h20435.www2.hp.com/t5/The-Next-Bench-Blog/HOW-TO-Disable-The-Fn-Function-on-HP-Laptops/ba-p/77527#.VRaZZvysXhc).  The Next Bench.  HP.

Comment: Unlikely; the reboot requirement is determined by the BIOS and how it works

Comment: ideally, if this can be done, *open source* software is preferable because it is the easiest to vet; equally good is software from a trusted website like Mark Russinovich's ["Windows Sysinternals"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) which has a gazillion useful utilities but AFAIK not one for this purpose.

Comment: if it can not be done, is there an *open source* or *trustworthy* utility that at least allows me to view the BIOS *while Windows is running*?

Comment: [DmiDecode for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm) might be useful. Not sure it will give you what you need re the HP action keys setting though. Source code is available (GPL).

Comment: Does HP BIOS Configuration Utility work with your HP model? http://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/whitepapers/BIOS_Configuration_Utility_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: DavidPostill ... i suspect this will work because it appears able to get and set BIOS settings; because i do not want to put my laptop at risk, i will check with HP support first; the good news is that the /Get option does show the current state of the *Action Key mode*.  `BiosConfigUtility64.exe` runs as a command line utility.  *ideally* i will be able to create a minimal settings file that touches only the *Action Key mode* and does not require a reboot.  `DmiDecode` looks interesting as a BIOS viewer too.  Your ideas are much appreciated.